# Is there a way to show index_advantage more friendly?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

Is there a way to show index_advantage more friendly like 99.54%?

```
SELECT TOP 25
user_seeks * avg_total_user_cost * (avg_user_impact * 0.01) AS [index_advantage]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats 
ORDER BY index_advantage DESC;
```

It shows a number like 41554133.7 so I want to show in percentage e.g. 99.54.

Comment: A percentage is a percentage of something else. It is a comparison of the value you have to some desired "gold standard" value. What is this "gold standard" for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Michael Green](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/36809/michael-green) noted, this doesn't trivially convert into a percentage. This query looks at the top 25 "scores", based on this formula; but those scores aren't based some known maximum.

If you looked at all the scores, they'd be based on query activity where SQL Server thinks an index that might help, not all SQL activity. And, of course, the numbers are much lower when you're server's been up for 1 day vs. 1 month.

Ultimately, I believe these scores are intended to give you a basis for comparison; a query scoring 2000000 is more likely worthwhile to look at than one scoring 200. - [RDFozz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/116653/rdfozz)